# Intervention causing reload of page?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm probably using it wrong and not understanding the purpose properly. But as a simple test, I added the following in my "master.blade.php" file:

```
if (!file_exists('images/cache/clients/'.$image)) {
    $img = Image::make('images/clients/'.$image)->resize(null, 50, true);
    $img->save('images/cache/clients/'.$image);
}
```

The problem is that when it hits this code, it basically reloads the entire frontpage. SO I see the content twice. It's like the make function actually does some header response of some kind.

All I want to do is resize the image, and save it to another location. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I have this in my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
        "codesleeve/stapler": "dev-master",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "0.3.*",
        "chumper/datatable": "dev-master",
        "moltin/laravel-cart": "dev-master",
        "intervention/image": "1.*",
        "opauth/opauth": "0.4.x",
        "artdarek/oauth-4-laravel": "dev-master"
},
```

I am unsure whether this should be added anywhere:

```
use Intervention\Image\Image;
```

([this page](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation) isn't exact if this should be added for laravel, or where it should be added for laravel)

I've got:

```
GD bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
PHP 5.5.11
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

**UPDATE2**

Make just does this:

```
public static function make($source)
{
    return new static($source);
}
```

I've tried wrapping make around an exception, no luck. But even if I do this:

```
public static function make($source)
{
    $bla = new static($source);
    print 'xxx'; die();
}
```

I don't see the print 'xxx' happening. If I put it before the "new static" part, I do see it. So basically, it's bombing on "new static". Is there any reason why this should happen on PHP 5.5?

** THINK I GOT IT **

I took everything out and placed it before the app even runs. Now I get this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\finfo_buffer()
```

[This](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/22) is saying libjpeg might be the issue, but it seems I do have it in my PhpInfo:

```
libJPEG Version 9 compatible
```

I'm running xampp, and apparrently I need this in the php.ini file:

```
 extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

I've added it but have to restart my machine to see the effect (dont ask, my xampp is broken)... will report back in a sec.

Comment: The `use Intervention\Image\Image;` should be placed where you call the `Image` class methods, place your code in your controller. Since you don't get an error/exception there is something different going on. Why don't you paste your entire view.

Comment: Best thing is to check whether you are placing your code in your Controller as per MVC coding principle. Placing your image code before the app start doesn't make sense. Your controller should take care of one-time code for certain views.

Comment: Yes, I know the coding practices/principles. I was just trying to debug the issue. Which I successfully managed to do using my "cowboy" tactics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not having fileinfo enabled. I added this in my php.ini file:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

That did the trick. A bit of a bummer that the addon didn't make it apparent.

Thanks for the downvote, but I'm sure this will help someone else trouble-shoot this problem.